# Drools 6.1.0 precompile using ANT or gradle

Tags: drools, precompile

Drools has built-in support for maven and the pre-compile is enable in maven scripts by the "kie-maven-plugin" maven plugin and the packaging using kjar.  However, if the build system is ANT or Gradle, what are the steps to enable the pre-compile on rules.?